# I have setup ADDS on a VM in GCP and I want to Connect my local machines/laptops/workstations to that domain controller how is this possible

Tags: google-cloud-platform, windows-server-2012, domaincontroller, windows-administration

I have setup ADDS on a VM in GCP and I want to Connect my local machines/laptops/workstations to that domain controller how is this possible

1. ADDS is setup but i am stuck at the part on how can i connect my workstations to that domain controller

SETUP of ADDS is completed

Comment: Are you using a VPN? If not, never put an Active Directory domain controller on the public Internet. Hackers will hit that server by the thousands and you will have an increased bill to pay GCP. The only way I would consider it is via a VPN that is properly configured. I recommend deleting the server in GCP. Create a virtual machine on your local computer and install Windows Server and Active Directory in the virtual machine.